# Find continuous duplicates in a List

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

There are loads of ways to find to find Duplicates in a list, is There any way to find continuous duplicates in a List.

For example

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
stringList.Add("Name1");
stringList.Add("Name2");
stringList.Add("Name1");
```

Shouldn't find any but

```
stringList.Add("Name1");
stringList.Add("Name1");
stringList.Add("Name2");
```

Should return 1 Entry

This returns duplicates.

```
 var q = listString.GroupBy(x => x)
         .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

Comment: What kind of result do you want? A true/false result, a list of the sections with duplicates?

Comment: Show the code you've written when you attempted to solve this so we can see where you went wrong. Don't forget to tell us why it isn't working. And debug your code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, If we can get which item is duplicate and starting index and number of occurances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just *store* the last item? Something like this

```
public static partial class EnumerableExtensions { 
  // Simplest; IEquatable<T> for advanced version
  public static IEnumerable<T> Continuous<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    if (null == source)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("source");  

    T lastItem = default(T);
    Boolean first = true;

    foreach (var item in source) {
      if (first) {
        lastItem = item;
        first = false;
      }
      else if (Object.Equals(item, lastItem)) 
        yield return item;
      else
        lastItem = item; 
    }
  }  
}
```

And then

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>() {
  "Name1",
  "Name1",
  "Name2",
};

var contDups = stringList
  .Continuous() 
  .ToList();
```

Comment: This Logic Works except Compiler error on this line (item == lastItem) as Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'. I Changed it to else if (item.Equals(lastItem)) and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Pankaj: I see, it should be `Object.Equals(item, lastItem)` - safier version (if any of `item`, `lastItem` are `null` ). See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it that returns the duplicate items and their indexes:

```
var duplicates =
    stringList
    .Select((x,i) => new {Item = x, Index = i})
    .Skip(1) //We start with the second item
    .Where(y => y.Item == stringList[y.Index-1])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Upvoted, However I am marking Dmitry answer as accepted as I tried his method first & it worked.

Comment: @Pankaj I think You should mark the best answer, not the first one. While working, Dmitry code does basically the same as .Skip(1).Where((y, i) => y == stringList[i])

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked "If we can get which item is duplicate and starting index and number of occurrences", here's a solution to that particular requirement.

This outputs the following:

```
2 was repeated 2 times starting at index 1
3 was repeated 3 times starting at index 4
4 was repeated 4 times starting at index 8
```

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class DupeInfo
    {
        public string Text;
        public int Index;
        public int Count;
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var test = new[]
            {
                "1",
                "2", "2",
                "A",
                "3", "3", "3",
                "B",
                "4", "4", "4", "4",
                "C",
            };

            foreach (var dupeinfo in FindRepeats(test))
                Console.WriteLine($"{dupeinfo.Text} was repeated {dupeinfo.Count} times starting at index {dupeinfo.Index}");
        }

        public static IEnumerable<DupeInfo> FindRepeats(IEnumerable<string> input)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int c = -1;

            string prev = null;

            foreach (var curr in input)
            {
                if (curr != prev)
                {
                    if (c >= 0)
                        yield return new DupeInfo {Text = prev, Count = c + 2, Index = j};

                    c = -1;
                    j = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++c;
                }

                prev = curr;
                ++i;
            }

            if (c >= 0)
                yield return new DupeInfo {Text = prev, Count = c + 2, Index = j};
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start from defining what it means for an item to be a "consecutive duplicate":

> An item at position `i` is a consecutive duplicate if it is the same as the item at position `i-1`

One way to compare a value with another value in a prior position is to use `Zip` with a list "shifted over" by one element:

```
var consecutiveDuplicates = list.Skip(1)
    .Zip(list, (me, prior) => new {ThisItem = me, Prior = prior})
    .Where(p => p.ThisItem == p.Prior)
    .Select(p => p.ThisItem) // Both sides are equal, pick either one
    .ToList();
```

`list.Skip(1).Zip(list,...)` expression combines the list with itself with a shift of 1, so you can get this element and its prior element for N-1 positions where prior element is defined. The rest is a straightforward translation of English definition into LINQ statements

Comment: Thanks Upvoted, However I am marking Dmitry answer as accepted as I tried his method first & it worked.