# Find duplicates in a list and return list with position of duplicates

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I know that there are tons of posts that deal with finding duplicates in a list.
Here is one
[Find continuous duplicates in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935592/find-continuous-duplicates-in-a-list)

What I would like is something more: returning a list in which are the positions of the string duplicates.

If the list is like **[0]=AAA** [1]=BBB **[3]=CCC [4]=AAA [5]=CCC**
I would like an extension that acts like;

```
var dupList = lst.FindDuplicatesReturnPositions();
```

dupList = 0,4,5 or even better 1,5,6.

Thanks in advance

Patrick

**ADD** I understand that I have not made it clear the reason why 1,5,6 instead than 0,4,5.
So as a code I prefer 0,4,5 but I have to apply that to a pallet matrix. And for customer who are NON coders cells start from 1 and not from 0. So not big deal to increment the numbers but if positions start from 1 it is better

Comment: Its unclear to me how you would get these index's. 0,4,5 and 1,5,6. Also we are all coders here, we like to see sample data written and implemented as actual code

Comment: 0,4,5 would be AAA,AAA,CCC. 1,5,6 would be BBB,CCC,??? (because index 6 is not included in your sample data). I fail to see how "AAA" and "CCC" or "BBB" and "CCC" can be considered string duplicates.

Comment: Why don't you just modify the method you are linking? Instead of making it return the value, return the position. Obviusly, to achieve this avoid the methods that order the list previously.

Comment: Please see my edit. Hope it is cleared now

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand why in the duplicate list there should be both 0 and 4 (for AAA) but not both 3 and 5 for (CCC)

Comment: Anyway... Funs over, its time to mark this question as needing details or clarity. Its unclear what you are asking, and how you get your results. If you could take time to fully explain the problem, double check your sample data and output indexes, this will likely be very answerable

Comment: Please see my comments below regarding the proposed solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have:

```
public static List<int> FindDuplicatesReturnPositions(this List<string> list)
{
   List<int> res = new List<int>();
   HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
   int index = 0; //int index = 1 if you want the other result
   foreach (var item in list)
   {
        if (hashSet.Contains(item))
        {
            res.Add(index);
        }
        else
        {
            hashSet.Add(item);
        }
        index++;
   }
            return res;
}
```

The way you should use is:

```
var dupList = FindDuplicatesReturnPositions(lst);
```

Comment: Here is my problem. if you run this on the OPs test data. you wont get the indexes specified

Comment: I have therefore to assume that indexes here start from 0 so if I have var lst = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { "AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","AAA","XXX","CCC","AAA" };
   var dupList = FindDuplicatesReturnPositions(lst); the result will be 5,7,8 that is "AAA", "CCC", "AAA". So that works thanks

Comment: The result of the OP data is obviously wrong.   
Indexes 0 and 4 are returned because they are duplicates. But just 5 is returned and not 3? 
Returning the 0 is a mistake, that's why my solution doesn't match the OPs test data.

Comment: [0]=AAA [1]=BBB [3]=CCC [4]=DDD [5]=AAA [6]=XXX [7]=CCC [8]=AAA so if you scan the list the first duplicate is [5]=AAA then [7]=CCC [8]=AAA ---> Thus 5,7,8

Comment: I meant the result the result provided in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Hi boy if you wanna list your duplicates list and sort them you can use this code but my code is example just . you can use this method . this work in controller api.

```
namespace Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class ListExamplesController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ListExamples listExamples = new ListExamples();
            var duplicatePets = listExamples.ReturnListOfPets()
                                            .GroupBy(x => x.StringValue)
                                            .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
                                            .Select(z => z.Key).ToList();
            var model = new ExampleOfListViewModel
            {
                ListOfPets              = listExamples.ReturnListOfPets(),
                ListOfInts              = listExamples.ReturnListOfInts(),
                ListOfStrings           = listExamples.ReturnListOfStrings(),
                ListOfIntsJoined        = listExamples.ReturnListOfIntsJoin(),
                ListOfPetsDuplicates    = duplicatePets,
                ListOfIntsSorted        = listExamples.SortReturnListOfInts()
            };
            return View("~/Views/Home/ListExamples.cshtml",model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah... so much to unpack here. Though what I do know is this answer completely misses the mark